# How do I read a file to and from a specific position?

Tags: c, file-io

Suppose I have a file like so:

```
card the red 
parrots massive
belt earth
```

If I want to read it from the 2nd position up to the 10th position and print it:

```
ard the r
```

How would I achieve this?

Comment: see `fseek()` and `fread()`, the manuals will help you.

Comment: Another way to acomplish it, is to use a `for`loop and read each char with `fgetc` and after your `counter variable` is on your specific position fill a char array with your chars from the file until your end position (When i == 1 until i == 9)

Comment: Read the whole line, change the end by putting the string terminator at the wanted position, and print from the second position.

Comment: Note that using e.g. `fseek` is problematic with text files where the lines are of varying length, and especially if you don't know the length of the line beforehand.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude good catch, took the liberty to add a little explanation on that issue to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

The most direct way is to use `fseek` and then `fread`. This code omits error checking for simplicity.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    FILE* f = fopen("File.txt", "r");
    fseek(f, 1, SEEK_SET);
    char buf[10];
    memset(buf, 0, 10);
    fread(buf, 1, 9, f);
    printf("%s\n", buf);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is simple enough to give some example code:

```
FILE *f = fopen("path/to/file", "r");
fseek(f, 1, SEEK_SET);  // set file pointer to 2nd position (0-indexed)
char part[10] = {0};    // array for 9 characters plus terminating 0
fread(part, 1, 9, f);   // read 9 members of size 1 (characters) from f into part
puts(part);             // or any other way to output part, like using in printf()
```

You need `#include <stdio.h>` for this and in real code, you have to **check all return values for errors that might happen**.

For more info, see for example the man pages of [`fseek()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fseek) and [`fread()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fread).

Note there are many other possible approaches, e.g. instead of *seeking*, you can just *read and forget* the first character, e.g. with `fgetc()`. See also [Some programmer dude's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51627719/c-how-do-i-read-a-file-to-and-from-a-specific-position#comment90220163_51627719) -- with a text file, reading from it will always give you a single `\n` for every line ending, no matter what your operating system uses, while `fseek()` operates on the real bytes on disk, where line endings could be encoded e.g. as `\r\n` (two bytes). So keep that in mind, it could introduce interesting bugs.

Answer (score 0):

if it's MFC application, CFile can be used:

```
char WBuf[]= "card the red parrots massive belt earth";
printf("WBuf = %s\n",WBuf); // WBuf = card the red parrots massive belt earth

CFile file;
file.Open("test.txt", CFile::modeCreate|CFile::modeNoTruncate|CFile::modeReadWrite);
file.Write(WBuf, sizeof(WBuf));             
file.Close();


// read   

char RBuf[30] = {0,};
file.Open("test.txt", CFile::modeRead);
file.Seek(1, CFile::begin);      // move file pointer 1time from the beginning of the file
file.Read(RBuf, 9);              // and then read 9bytes
file.Close();

printf("RBuf = %s\n", RBuf);     // RBuf = ard the r
```